# screen recording software with specific resolution

Tags: windows, screen-recording

I am using windows 10. My laptop screen resolution is 1080p. However I want to record the screen (along with the system audio), such the the screen recording is done in a custom resolution(say 360p). I don't want to first record in 1080p and then scale it down. Can you suggest a free software that can do the job? An open-source recommendation will be more preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/), a free, multi-platform screen capture/streaming/video editing program appears to do as you require.

From a [photography/video tutorial site](https://photography.tutsplus.com/tutorials/obs-for-screen-recording-video-and-output-settings--cms-28542), this specific screen shows that the program can be configured as you request:

[image: capture and output settings]

As shown in the image, the input and output resolutions are adjustable, as is the output frame rate and the algorithm for downscaling the video.